# Spring Boot disable R2dbcAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, spring-autoconfiguration

I'm trying to create a `ConnectionFactory` bean and so I want to disable the `R2dbcAutoConfiguration`.

I tried the following so far:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class)`

and

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class)`

but neither of them work since a `ConnectionFactory` is still getting created on `ConnectionFactoryConfigurations` at `PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration`.

And because of that I get this error:

> The bean 'connectionFactory', defined in class path resource [com/example/config/CustomR2dbcAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration$PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties( R2dbcProperties.class )
@ConditionalOnResource( resources = "classpath:META-INF/services/io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactoryProvider" )
@EnableAutoConfiguration( exclude = { R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class } )
public class CustomR2dbcAutoConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        return ConnectionFactories.get( "r2dbc:postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/test" );
    }
}
```

I don't want to override the bean. I want it not to get created in the first place.

Any help is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are several configruation depends on the `R2dbcAutoConfiguration`. In my simple chat messages application, I only want to use the Postgres `Connection`, and use the following config to build a R2dbc `connectionFacotry` bean from scratch, it works well.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        R2dbcAutoConfiguration.class,
        R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        R2dbcTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Slf4j
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(
                PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .database("blogdb")
                        .username("user")
                        .password("password")
                        //.codecRegistrar(EnumCodec.builder().withEnum("post_status", Post.Status.class).build())
                        .build()
        );
    }

// other beans
```

The complete example project is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/pg-notifier-listener/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation on your custom ConnectionFactory bean to indicate that it should only be created if a ConnectionFactory bean is not already present in the application context.

Or you should add @Primary on your custom connectionFactory
@Primary
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
{
return ConnectionFactories.get( "r2dbc:postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/test" );
}

Comment: If I use the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` it will not create my custom ConnectionFactory. With the `@Primary` the other ConnectionFactory still gets created which I don't want.

Comment: You could disable the default ConnectionFactory then by adding spring.r2dbc.url=none on your application.properties files